# getting first day when pandas column value falls below threshold for n consecutive days

Tags: python, pandas

```
    Unnamed: 0       index    datetime  ... cVI     Region    average_daily_temp
0            0  2000-01-01  2000-01-01  ...   NaN  Central           -5.883996
1            1  2000-01-02  2000-01-02  ...   NaN  Central           -6.715087
2            2  2000-01-03  2000-01-03  ...   NaN  Central           -6.074254
3            3  2000-01-04  2000-01-04  ...   NaN  Central           -4.222387
4            4  2000-01-05  2000-01-05  ...   NaN  Central           -0.994825
5            5  2000-01-06  2000-01-06  ...   NaN  Central           -0.134637
6            6  2000-01-07  2000-01-07  ...   NaN  Central           -1.422975
7            7  2000-01-08  2000-01-08  ...   NaN  Central           -1.203469
8            8  2000-01-09  2000-01-09  ...   NaN  Central           -1.434409
9            9  2000-01-10  2000-01-10  ...   NaN  Central           -3.064248
10          10  2000-01-11  2000-01-11  ...   NaN  Central           -2.786777
11          11  2000-01-12  2000-01-12  ...   NaN  Central           -2.014506
12          12  2000-01-13  2000-01-13  ...   NaN  Central           -3.724021
13          13  2000-01-14  2000-01-14  ...   NaN  Central           -7.520119
14          14  2001-01-15  2000-01-15  ...   NaN  Central           -2.211982
15          15  2001-01-16  2000-01-16  ...   NaN  Central           -4.061025
16          16  2001-01-17  2000-01-17  ...   NaN  Central           -5.902755
17          17  2001-01-18  2000-01-18  ...   NaN  Central           -2.219055
18          18  2001-01-19  2000-01-19  ...   NaN  Central           -3.658139
19          19  2001-01-20  2000-01-20  ...   NaN  Central           -8.308456
20          20  2000-01-21  2000-01-21  ...   NaN  North           -5.373433
21          21  2000-01-22  2000-01-22  ...   NaN  North           -11.931772
22          22  2000-01-23  2000-01-23  ...   NaN  North           -11.164742
23          23  2000-01-24  2000-01-24  ...   NaN  North           -11.138757
24          24  2000-01-25  2000-01-25  ...   NaN  North           -16.334695
25          25  2002-01-26  2000-01-26  ...   NaN  North           -12.841963
26          26  2002-01-27  2000-01-27  ...   NaN  North           -6.340999
27          27  2002-01-28  2000-01-28  ...   NaN  North           0.987073
28          28  2002-01-29  2000-01-29  ...   NaN  North           0.819165
29          29  2002-01-30  2000-01-30  ...   NaN  North           -1.665307
```

In the dataframe above, I want to find for each combination of `Region` and year (year can be derived from datetime column), what is the first day when `average_daily_temp` falls below a value of -3 for atleast 3 consecutive days. How do I do that?

Comment: what happens when the temperature is below -3 for more than 3 days, e.g. 4 days? Do you select the first day or do you select the first two days?

Comment: I select the first day in that scenario. Updated question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's create an additional boolean column that indicates if the "average_daily_temp" is under the threshold:

```
df["under_threshold"] = df["average_daily_temp"] < -3
```

Now, we know that we want to group by "Region" and year, and for each group we want to find the first of 3 or more consecutive dates where the temperature is under a threshold. The easy part:

```
df.groupby(["Region", df["datetime"].dt.year]).apply(first_of_3_or_more_cold_days)
```

Finally, we only have to define a function that receives a dataframe (where everey row will have the same values for "Region" and year) and returns the first row of the consecutive group that matches our condition. We will compare each row with the two right below and see if all of them have a `True` value in "under_threshold":

```
lambda group: (group.loc[group["under_threshold"].shift(-2) & group["under_threshold"].shift(-1) & group["under_threshold"]]).head(1)
```

We're comparing the third row (`.shift(-2)`) with the middle row (`.shift(-1)`) and the first row of each group of 3 consecutive rows. If all of them have a `True` value in "under_threshold" it means that we're inside a group that matches the condition. Since you only care about the first day of the first group that matches this condition, we take `.head(1)`.

---

Resulting code:

```
df["under_threshold"] = df["average_daily_temp"] < -3
x = df.groupby(["Region", df.datetime.dt.year]).apply(
    lambda group_df: (group_df.loc[group_df["under_threshold"].shift(-2) & group_df["under_threshold"].shift(-1) & group_df["under_threshold"]]).head(1).reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
                         index   datetime  ...  average_daily_temp under_threshold
Region  datetime                           ...                                    
Central 2000     0  2000-01-01 2000-01-01  ...           -5.883996            True
North   2000     0  2000-01-21 2000-01-21  ...           -5.373433            True
```